# What does "make us dream" mean?

Tags: phrase-request

I am trying to understand what "make us dream" exactly means because a friend of mine asked me what it means in our language. Actually I know what it means but I just couldn't make a good translation for him.

It is a banner of Liverpool FC and the title of a book written by a fan as well.

How would you explain or paraphrase "make us dream" in English?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "dream" is the second in Cambridge [to imagine something that you would like to happen:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/dream_2)

The banner is saying, from the point of view of the fans, "(By playing very good football) *make us dream* (that we might be able to win the championship)"

The "make us" is used instead of "let us" as it is more forceful and more hopeful.